# How to link a view row to a node?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm using the [Message module](https://drupal.org/project/message) to notify users when someone reacted on their nodes. I'm now trying to theme the messages, which are displayed in a view, called 'Message'.

I'd like to link a message to the content that's commented on. In other words: when a user clicks a message, he/she should be linked to the corresponding node's page. I don't simply want the message text to be a link, but the whole message (i.e. also including the other fields) should function as some kind of 'button'.

I think the easiest way to do this is to create a `views-view-unformatted--message.tpl.php` file and use

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
   <a href="<?php print url('$url'); ?>">
    <?php print $row; ?>
   </a>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to define `$url`. I can store the needed `nid` in the message and add it hidden to the view, but I can't find a way to grab that information.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stored the `nid` from the node that's commented on in a message field and used the information in a `views-view-unformatted--message.tpl.php` file.

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <?php $message = message_load($view->result[$id]->mid); ?>      
  <div <?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
   <a href="<?php if (isset ($message->field_nid['und'][0]['value'])) {
                      print url('node/'.$message->field_nid['und'][0]['value']);} ?>">
    <?php print $row; ?>
   </a>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```